# Inner-product on skew-hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, inner-products

Let
$$\mathfrak{u}(n)=\{X\in M(n,\Bbb C):X+X^*=0\}$$
where $X^*$ is the conjugate transpose. Then, $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ is a *real* vector space.

> **Problem.** Show that $\langle X,Y\rangle=\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}\Tr(XY^*)$ is a *real* inner-product on $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ that is invariant under conjugation by $U(n)$.

---

**Attempts.**

The part about conjugation by $U(n)$ is easy:
$$\Tr((UXU^{-1})(UYU^{-1})^*)=\Tr(UXU^{-1}UY^*U^*)=\Tr(UXY^*U^{-1})=\Tr(XY^*)$$
since the trace is invariant under conjugation.

But now, I don't know how to prove that $\Tr(XY^*)$ is an inner-product.

It is clear every matrix in $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ is normal and hence unitarily diagonalizable. So $X\sim \DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}\diag(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $Y\sim \diag(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ where $a_i,b_i\in\Bbb R$. My guess is that 
$$\Tr(XY^*)=a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n,$$
and hence it is a real inner-product. This is true if $X$ and $Y$ are diagonal. But I can't prove it in general.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be a matter of checking the four properties of an inner product, of which three of them are almost trivial?

Comment: I am curious to understand why you would like to restrict this product to $u(n)$. This product is the most natural inner product on $M(n,C)$ whit associated quadratic form the sum of square of module of entries of the matrix.

Comment: Note that this inner product is simply the "dot-product" using the matrix entries.

Comment: @Thomas That's not a real inner-product, but a hermitian one.

Comment: Is the vector space real? Doesn't $X + X* = 0$ only imply that the diagonal is $0+\alpha i$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and  that $Re(-X) = Re(X^T)$ and $Im(X) = Im(X^T)$ with $Im(-X) = Im(\overline{X})$ Or did I a stupid mistake?

Comment: @PatrickAbraham The entries are not necessarily real, but the set $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ has the structure of a real vector space: it is closed under addition and multiplication by real numbers. Note that it is *not* closed under multiplication by complex numbers and hence is not a complex vector space.

Comment: But the real part of an hermitian product is an euclidian product, and the restriction of this product to $u(n)$ is rela , right ?

Comment: @user350977 I am used to the notation, is "closed under addition and skalarmultiplication by real numbers".